# How to export multiple html tables in one csv file in angular?

Tags: html, angular, excel, html-table

I have multiple html tables in one file. and I want to export all tables in csv file.

I am using "XLSX" package .

```
 exportAsXLSX() {
        let element = document.querySelectorAll('csv-table');
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);
        const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'sheet1');
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);       
    }
```

Is there any other method so i can export all my tables in one csv file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there's no need to use the `xlsx` library in this case. You certainly created your `HTML` tables based on a data model present in your component class. Therefore, you could simply join the data from the different tables and write them all together to a `CSV` file.

This could be done with the following service (code borrowed from [koia.io](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/export.service.ts)).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CSVExportService {

  private static readonly TYPE_CSV = 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8';

  private newline = '\n';
  private datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
  private timeFormat = 'yyyy-mm-dd_HHmmss';

  exportAsCSV(data: Object[], baseFileName: string): void {
    const csv = this.toCSV(data, ',');
    const blob: Blob = new Blob([csv], { type: CSVExportService.TYPE_CSV });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, this.generateFileName(baseFileName, '.csv'));
  }

  private toCSV(data: Object[], delimiter: string): string {
    const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    return keys.join(delimiter) + this.newline +
      data.map(e => this.toCSVLine(e, keys, delimiter))
        .join(this.newline);
  }

  private toCSVLine(element: Object, keys: string[], delimiter: string) {
    return keys.map(k => element[k])
      .join(delimiter);
  }

  private generateFileName(baseFileName: string, extension: string): string {
    const formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date().getTime(), this.timeFormat);
    return baseFileName + '_' + formattedDate + extension;
  }
}
```